# Android, Volley Request, the response is blocking main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-volley

Something bad is happening when using Volley to treat a large response:

```
String url = AppHelper.DOMAIN + "/service/pages/profile_update.json";

this.infoTextView.setText(getString(R.string.profile_info_updating));

final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

                    if (json.getBoolean("success")) {
                        // manage JSON object here
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,
                                getString(R.string.connection_problem_server),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    ProfileActivity.this.infoTextView.setText(
                            getString(R.string.profile_info_updating_error));

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        ProfileActivity.this.infoTextView.setText(
                getString(R.string.profile_info_updating_error));

        if (error.networkResponse != null && error.networkResponse.statusCode == 401) {
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,
                    getString(R.string.connection_problem_permission),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (ProfileActivity.this.swipeRefreshLayout != null) {
                    ProfileActivity.this.swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
        }, 1000);

        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("auth_token", ProfileActivity.this.defaultUser.getAuthenticationToken());
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.putAll(super.getHeaders());
        params.put("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            GZIPInputStream gStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.data));
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gStream);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader, 16384);

            String read;

            while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(read).append("\n");
            }
            reader.close();
            in.close();
            gStream.close();
        } catch (IOException error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            return Response.error(new ParseError());
        }

        return Response.success(output.toString(), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }
};

stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
    @Override
    public int getCurrentTimeout() {
        // 40 seconds
        return 40000;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
        return DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES;
    }

    @Override
    public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {
        throw error;
    }
});

Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
```

this code block the main thread, freezing the application.

Additionally, I set some header values to allow gzip response and a code to handle the data. But it is not the piece that make the undesired behavior. The application freeze only when `onResponse(String response)` starts.

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that you're doing the JSON parsing on the UI thread, instead of in `parseNetworkResponse`

Comment: Code seems to be fine.. could you expose other part of code around this network request?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

onResponse and onErrorResponse is called on UI thread hence any heavy operation done inside these methods will make you application less responsive. I guess you are trying to parse the response in onResponse() which is incorrect.

> You have to move to parsing logic to parseNetworkResponse since this
>   is the method which is called in background thread. Refer the below link for more details :

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html

Comment: what if the call request was made from `IntentService`, will `onResponse()` execute on UI thread then?

Comment: Doest not matter what is the calling thread. onResponse() will be called on UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

If it help someone , try to create a new thread in a method inside onResponse , inside that thread execute your parsing data. I hope the answer works for you

Comment: Hi, as explained in the accepted answer 4 years ago, response processing should be done in `parseNetworkResponse` which already runs on a worker thread.