# How can I parse a large JsonArray from Volley request response

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-volley

I work on an Android project.
I have a Volley request that return me a Object reponse.
This reponse was a String of JsonArray with x JsonObject inside.
JsonArray was over 40MB.
How can I parse this JsonArray ?

Comment: You are receiving a 40MB JSONArray String? oO Or what is "Mo"?

Comment: Sorry, Mo is the french word for MB ( 1Mo = 1MB ).

Comment: Did you try `JSONArray response = new JSONArray(your40MBString);`?

Comment: Yes, I try : `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray((String) response);` I have some memory logs like : _07-10 18:01:41.504 5447-5457/com.I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 73958(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(96MB) LOS objects, 6% free, 225MB/241MB, paused 2.009ms total 109.478ms Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc_

Comment: may be help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/38567917/3475580

Comment: use Gson for parsing.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volley is not really suitable for handling large responses. You might also run into problems like this question- [Android, Volley Request, the response is blocking the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567604/android-volley-request-the-response-is-blocking-main-thread). I believe using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [OK Http](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with okhttp

> volley store whole http response contents as byte[] in memory and then convert to String or Json or other type, so it can not handle huge response, you should use okhttp instead.

https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/issues/80#issuecomment-138433200